# Dynamically set UserControl as Listbox DataTemplate body

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

I have the following setup:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Targets}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <view:ViewName />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to dynamically decide which view to use at runtime, based on a property within the `DataContext` of the `ListBox`. In simple terms, I want to replace `<view:ViewName>` with a data binding that returns the proper view.

I use MEF to provide plug-ins for my app that may need to provide a custom view to display the items when appropriate. At design time I won't know all the possible view types (they may be dynamically loaded from a DLL) so a simple `DataTemplateSelector` won't do.

I have researched solutions but have come up empty.

Comment: are you ok with using some other helper class or similar - as long as your view view-model is just one - and single property - or more properties in your VM. There're many solutions to this, I'll try to write something later on - I just need to know what's the goal. E.g. see this one with `flags` solution (solution 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550344/genrating-views-usercontrols-using-contentcontrol/15550477#15550477 - (and you can map that for more than just 'two' choices etc.) - but there is a better way I'm often utilizing.

Comment: I don't have a problem with using  a helper/converter/etc. I just can use a solution that requires me to list all the possible choices at design time in the xaml, since I won't know them then. I guess the simplest way to demonstrate what I need is to add a hypotheical attribute to DataTemplate as: `<DataTemplate View="{Binding View}"/>` where View is a property in the DataTemplate for the ListBox.

Comment: probably a string containing the name of the view. I can arrange for all the views to be in the same namespace, even the dynamic ones, I think. And above I meant "the DataContext for the ListBox", but I just ran out of editing time

Comment: ...but you do have all the possible templates (for the views) known before hand, right? i.e. you have a finite number of views you plan to 'engage' - based on that string/ID.

Comment: No, that is where I am running into trouble. I want be able to have new Action classes dynamically loaded via MEF that may have new Views associated with them. At runtime the steps are created from a configuration script in XML that references the Action for each step. I want to be able to have 3rd parties in my oranization be able to create new Actions without having to re-release the core software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `DataTemplateManager` from [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way) You can do something like:

```
DataTemplateManager.RegisterDataTemplate<ViewModelType1, ViewType1>();
DataTemplateManager.RegisterDataTemplate<ViewModelType2, ViewType2>();
DataTemplateManager.RegisterDataTemplate<ViewModelType3, ViewType3>();
```

then you would remove the `ItemTemplate` from the ListBox:

```
<ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Targets}"/>
```

and in the ListBox ViewModel you could:

```
public void AddTargets()
{
    Targets.Add(new ViewModelType1());
    Targets.Add(new ViewModelType2());
    Targets.Add(new ViewModelType3());
}
```

Then, each `DataTemplate` will be automatically used by WPF to render each corresponding ViewModel.

Also note that you can call `DataTemplateManager.RegisterDataTemplate()` at any time before showing the ListBox, so you can theoretically do that when loading the MEF parts.

Edit:

Based on your comment, you could create a single DataTemplate with a ContentPresenter to display the selected View according to a property in the ViewModel:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TargetViewModel}">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MainContentPresenter" Content="{Binding}" ContentTemplate="{Binding YourProperty, Converter=SomeConverter}"/>
```

and inside the SomeConverter you should use the same technique as demonstrated in the post, to dynamically generate a DataTemplate.

Comment: That is awesome and so close to what I really want to do. I could probably work with it if I had to. But what I really want is to choose my view based on a property within a single view model, not to have separate view models for each view. I have a TargetViewModel with an Action property of type IAction. The individual concrete classes implementing IAction can provide the name of the view to display. So in an ideal world, the ListBox would use TargetViewModel.Action.View to determine the view to display.

Comment: This worked great. I just had to come to the realization that I needed separate view models for each Action. I was going to run into further issues down the road trying to work with specific Action classes through an IAction reference anyway. This way I have a view model with a Concrete Action member of the right type, so that my view can get at the info it needs. The provider of the Action needs to proved a view model now, but I abstracted most of the work into a base class. It works great and is a better solution than the one I was originally looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to change templates based on a bound value, you can use a `DataTrigger` to determine the `ContentTemplate` of the `ListBoxItem`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Property="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="A">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateA}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I find this better than using a `DataTemplateSelector` because it gets re-evaluated if the bound property changes, while a `DataTemplateSelector` does not.

If you want to change templates based on an object type, you can use Implicit `DataTemplates`. These are `DataTemplates` that define a `DataType`, but no `x:Key`, and they will be used anytime WPF tries to draw an object of the specified type.

For example, if you had this template defined in your `<X.Resources>` somewhere

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type models:ActionA}">
    <views:ActionAView />
</DataTemplate>
```

you could then insert your Model object directly into the UI and WPF would draw it using the template you specified

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SomeIActionObject}" />

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfIActionObjects}" />
```

**Update**

You mentioned that you would be allowing users to create modules with additional Templates that get imported using MEF, so in that case you would probably be better off using an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that look up the matching template within `Application.Resources`

For example, if the bound value equals `"A"`, then the converter might search `Application.Resources` for a template named `"TemplateA"` and return it to the binding

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" 
            Value="{Binding SomeProperty, 
                Converter={StaticResource MyTemplateConverter}}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: That would actually work really well, except that I don't know the set of possible values at design time to create the static resources.

Comment: @user1394408 Well you have to create your `Templates` in advance don't you? You can't just write "if Property = Z then use TemplateZ" and not have TemplateZ defined somewhere. I suppose you could use a `Converter` instead of a DataTrigger though, that would look at the bound property and then search the `Application.Resources` for a template that matched that property and return it.

Comment: what @Rachel is saying makes lot of sense - you need to have something fixed, at some point - or how is that you plan to do it

Comment: My template is always just a simple wrapper around a view (containing a UserControl). The views would be the dynamic part. The issue is they can be loaded dynamically using MEF, so I would not know what they are at design time

Comment: @user1394408 That makes sense. If that's the case, then I would try to use a Converter to lookup the template needed for the bound value and return it to the UI. See the update to my question :)

Comment: I went with the DataTemplateManager solution below. It works great with MEF. I just needed to rethink the problem (see my comment below). Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1394408 No problem :) As an alternative to a `DataTemplateManager`, you can also use Implicit DataTemplates if you're basing your view on an object type. Less code involved :)